# using get_the_category to get all post categories except one

Tags: tags, conditional-tags

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $cat) {
if (!($cat->cat_name=='Featured')) echo $cat->cat_name . ' ';
}
```

this is what has been recommended in the forums but its not working for me.  I need to split off the echo piece like the following to show an image.

```
<li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/cats/<?php echo $category->slug ?>-icon.png"/>  <?php  echo $category->cat_name ?> </li>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $cat) {
    if ($cat->cat_name != 'Featured') {
        echo '<li><img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/cats/' . $cat->slug . '-icon.png"/>' . $cat->cat_name . '</li>';
    }
}
```